# Animate HTML element on scroll position

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll, loading

What I would try to do is to animate via CSS3 some HTML when the **scrollbar** reach a **certain position**.

I navigated through **jQuery** plugins founding lots of interesting things such as parallax or harmonic scrolls,and the closest thing I found is the popular **lazy load** which delay the loading of images while scrolling the page.
What I'd like to do is something like that but with animated *div* or *img* or *a*.

I hope somebody can direct me to some good plugins who can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the jQuery `scrollTop()` function with the `scroll` event. Maybe like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     var top = $(this).scrollTop();
     if(top > 150){
         //do something after it scrolls down past 150px    
     }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm going to try it right now... I'll let you know!
Thanks for now!

Comment: Wow this definitely works thanks!

I tried with some basic animation and it's very good!
Is there anyway to make an HTML take place to the moment I scroll to a certain position so I can define animation through CSS3. Since the DIV would be started by Javascript the animation will start along the creation of the DIV by jQuery...

Thanks again!

Comment: Might want to do something with the `.addClass('animateThis');` function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs, you are looking for something like [**Transe**](https://github.com/yckart/jQuery.transe.js/). It allows you to transform and animate elements depeding on the current scroll-offset.

Here's a super simple demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ARTsinn/mqcTr/

https://github.com/yckart/jQuery.transe.js/

Another solution is [Scrollorama](https://github.com/johnpolacek/scrollorama).

Comment: Thank you very much yckart, this is for sure a very interesting plugin. Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for.
I don't need to modify the properties of animation while scrolling, I just need some breakpoints where, as the page is scrolled on them, the DIV appears showing it's content with some cool animation.

But once it's appeared it stays there!

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you may want to combine the scroll with the actual CSS3 animation (and, further below, eventually the div position while scrolling), which is lacking in the previous answers:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     var top = $(this).scrollTop();
     if(top > 150){
         document.getElementById("some_div_element").style.animationName = "some_animation_name";   
     }
});
```

A css style property for `some_div_element` can be initialized with sth else than `some_animation_name`, hence the animation is triggered once this style property is changed by the scroll position:

```
div.some_div_element {
   background-color:rgb(140, 20, 20);
   animation-name: undefined_bla;
}
```

... and used with an animation defition for `some_animation_name`, e.g.:

```
@keyframes some_animation_name {
   from {background-color:rgb(140, 20, 20);}
   to {background-color:rgb(200, 20, 20);} 
}
```

With div elements however, its often not the scroll position itself but the distance of the element to, e.g., the displayed page top that matters to initiate an animation:

```
window.onscroll = function() {dist_to_top_function()};
function dist_to_top_function() {
   var dist = document.getElementById("some_div_element").getBoundingClientRect().top;
   if(dist < 600){    // distance in px
         document.getElementById("some_div_element").style.animationName = "some_animation_name";          
   }        
}
```

The js if-statement may also contain modifications on the div style to make them permanently match the end result of the animation, e.g.,

```
...    
document.getElementById("some_div_element").style.backgroundColor= "rgb(200, 20, 20);";
```